# How to send emails with my own email server installed locally

Tags: php, email, configuration, iis-6, mail-server

I have installed my mail enabled professional copy on the same server as php is installed (and wordpress) and I want to use the mail server when people enter emails forms etc.

I started with looking on simple email scripts but they all have failed and I have been googling for at least 8-9 hours on different solutions on scripts with sendmail, scripts using gmail, and lots of options that almost all require PEAR or some other solution - and I have thrown in the towel before I start tearing my hair out in frustration..

So Now I want to go with this option as it’s simpler for me and I do already own a license to mail enable.

How can I accomplish this?

I have the newest version of php available... Server is a Windows server 2003 ENT with IIS 6 installed and MySQL server/wordpress.

I am not a programmer - just a "normal" guy.. I know to get around with computers - most of the time - but coding Is like greek to me! (Which in this case might be my Achilles heel)

Comment: Are you having wordpress setup up and running on windows server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.

These libraries make it trivial to configure your mail server to send emails with.

Mailenable should provide you with a smtp server and credentials.

Here's an example with phpmailer :
http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp